# evaluating piecewise function (Error in curve(..., : 'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n')

Tags: r

I am trying to create a piecewise function using R. I am having trouble with my plot function

```
a <- function(x){
ifelse(( x <-1),0,ifelse((-1<x & x<2),(x^3+1)/9ifelse((x>2),1,NA)))
}
plot(a,xlim=c(-5,5), ylim = c(-4, 7), col = "red")
```

I am not sure if I never created my function properly or if there is something wrong with the way that I have plotted it. The piecewise function is a little confusing because it's a straight line of 1 and 0 at its intervals and from -1 to 2 it's a weird function.

Answer (score 1):

There are two typos in your function; one is tricky.

(1) missing a comma before the third `ifelse` (this is probably a cut-and-paste error); (2) in `x<(-1)`, you need parentheses (or at least a space) so R doesn't think you're assigning the value 1 to `x` (i.e. `x <- 1`).

```
a <- function(x) {
    ifelse(( x <(-1)),0,ifelse((-1<x & x<2),(x^3+1)/9,
                        ifelse((x>2),1,NA)))
}
plot(a,xlim=c(-5,5), ylim = c(-4, 7), col = "red")
```